# Twitter-Bootstrap form validation style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my html code :

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-errors" id="password-group">
    <input type="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control" id="password">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback has-error"></span>
    <p class="help-block" id="password-error">The password must be at least 6 characters.</p><p class="help-block" id="password-error">The password confirmation does not match.</p>
</div>
```

and this screen cap of my form :
[image]

Normally the form should have the error style( in red).so what I've missed here?

Note I'm using Jquery to add the error tags, I'm using server validation via JSON :

```
$form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-errors');
$form.find('.form-group').addClass('has-errors');
var field = errors[key];
for ( var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
  var $group = $form.find('#' + key + '-group');
  //add the error class and set the error text
  $group.remove('#' + key + '-error');
  $group.append('<p id="'+ key + '-error" class="help-block">'+ field[i]+'</p>');
}
```

Comment: Nothing in your code makes it red, can you attach CSS file?

Comment: @ErezHaim I'm using twitter bootstrap CSS file

Comment: Ohh thannk's you saved my day :D post your comment in seperate answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says `has-errors`, but the Bootstrap class is just `has-error`

Also thought I should point out that it looks like your javascript is generating two different elements with `id="password-error"`. Multiple elements with the same id attribute is not valid HTML.